# What is the interpretation of the fundamental theorem of line integrals?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

The fundamental theorem of line integrals is:

$$\int_{a}^{b} \nabla F \cdot \vec{dr} = F(r(b)) - F(r(a))$$ for some curve traced by $r$.

What is the intuition for why this is true?

The proof is straightforward, but I cannot extend it.

[image]

Comment: How much physics do you know? Do you know about work and energy? Specifically, does the equation $\text{work} = \int_{a}^{b}\boldsymbol{F}\cdot\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{r}$ look familiar? Here $\boldsymbol{F}$ represents a force and $\boldsymbol{r}$ is the position vector of an object, and this equation comes from the equation $\text{work} = \text{force }\times\text{ distance}$.

Comment: Doesn't the proof itself give you some intuition?  Once you parametrize your path, you've just got the scalar derivative of a function of a scalar then you use the FTC.  In what way would you like to extend this theorem?

Comment: Is there any geometric interpretation to the theorem? amd explains that $\nabla f$ implies a conservative field, so, yeah, it makes sense that only endpoints matter in the integral's evaluation. I was hoping that something about the gradient vector being tangent to a surface might also explain this theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a mathematical point of view, this theorem is just a generalization of 
$$
\int_a^b f(t) \;dt =\int_a^b F'(t) \;dt =F(b)-F(a),
$$
where $F(t)$ is an antiderivative of $f(t)$. This essentially says that to compute an integral of a function that has an antiderivative, it is sufficient to compute the difference of the antiderivative between both endpoints of the interval. If there is more than one variable, the concept of gradient is in some sense equivalent to the concept of derivation, so the theorem becomes
$$
\int_C \vec{f}(x,y) \cdot d\vec{r} =\int_C \nabla F(x,y)\cdot d\vec{r} =F(\vec{r}(b))-F(\vec{r}(a)).
$$

From a more physical point of view, this theorem states that the integral does not depend on the curve $C$, but only on the endpoints of $C$. In other words, you can integrate on the curve that you want, you will get the same result, provided the starting and stopping point remain the same. This is very powerful and useful in physics, for example when you need to compute the energy (or work) done by a vector field (for example gravity) to move an object from one end point to another. If the field can be expressed as the gradient of a function (it is the case for gravity), then you don't need to know the trajectory of the object, you only need to know the endpoints.

This is how the common formula
$$
W_{\vec{P}}=mgh 
$$
is proved. The work done by the weight field $\vec{P}$ only depends on constants $m$ and $g$, and on the difference of altitude of the object, i.e. on the initial and final position of the object. Whatever the object did between these positions is not important.

Answer (score 1):

An example that I keep in mind for this is that of a force field that gives the resistance to infinitesimal motion at each point, such as that of gravity. The line integral then gives you the work done in moving along a given path. When the force field has a conservation law (hence the term “conservative”), the integral will depend only on the end points of the path.